# Compare the values of same products from past and present

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I am very new with R and need to solve a problem. So need your help. I have 3 people A, B, C, selling different products like car, house, watch, dress, jewellery etc at 2009 and again 2020.

For year 2009

```
People  car  house watch dress jewel
A       1000 10000 30    5     50
B       2000 7987  68    9     78
C       6977 4746  99    56    367
```

For year 2020

```
People  car  house watch dress jewel
A       8700 10800 39    7     44
B       8900 9987  46    56    134
C       2577 40046 100   50    399
```

Now if I want to compare the selling price for the things for two different years what would be my code?

I want a file like:

```
People  car       house        watch dress jewel
A       8700/1000 10800/10000  etc.
B       8900/2000 9987/7987    etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both datasets by rows and calculate ratios by `People` with `aggregate()`.

(`rbind()` also matches column names of both datasets)

```r
aggregate(. ~ People, rbind(df1, df2), \(x) x[2] / x[1])

#   People       car    house     watch     dress    jewel
# 1      A 8.7000000 1.080000 1.3000000 1.4000000 0.880000
# 2      B 4.4500000 1.250407 0.6764706 6.2222222 1.717949
# 3      C 0.3693565 8.437842 1.0101010 0.8928571 1.087193
```

---

If you're not familiar with `aggregate()`, you could try the following easier way that uses `match()` to consider the order of `People`:

```r
cbind(df2[1], df2[-1] / df1[match(df2$People, df1$People), colnames(df2)][-1])

#   People       car    house     watch     dress    jewel
# 1      A 8.7000000 1.080000 1.3000000 1.4000000 0.880000
# 2      B 4.4500000 1.250407 0.6764706 6.2222222 1.717949
# 3      C 0.3693565 8.437842 1.0101010 0.8928571 1.087193
```

---

###### Data

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
People  car  house watch dress jewel
A       1000 10000 30    5     50
B       2000 7987  68    9     78
C       6977 4746  99    56    367", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
People  car  house watch dress jewel
A       8700 10800 39    7     44
B       8900 9987  46    56    134
C       2577 40046 100   50    399", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dead simple solution without using any packages, only plain "base" R.

Assume you have your data in two dataframes, `data2009` and `data2020`, and **exactly the same** People column in both vectors

```r
# optionally copy data 2020 in a new data frame for the  relative prices, 
# in case you want to keep the old one, data2020, intact if you need it later

relativeprice <- data2020

# now replace the 2020 prices by the relative prices

relativeprice$car <- data2020$car / data2009$car
relativeprice$house <- data2020$house / data2009$house
```

@DarrenTsai pointed out that you should take care of eventual changes in the `People` column, and use

```
relativeprice$car <- data2020$car /
    data2009$car[match(data2020$People, data2009$People)]
```

instead.

Darren Tsai's solution does not use extra packages, either.

Comment: You have assumed both datasets have equal order and length of `People`. A much safer way is `relativeprice$car <- data2020$car / data2009$car[match(data2020$People, data2009$People)]`

Comment: Yes, you are right, People could have changed, thanks! I include your comment into the answer! (we wrote our answers at the same time, and I was going for a most beginner friendly version, but it is dangerous as you say)